# Where should I check variable type with PHP 7?

Tags: php, types, nullable

With the arrival of version 7 PHP introduced scalar types, nullable scalar types and return types. Using these are immediately beneficial (self documenting code, fatal errors at run-time, the list goes on) but i'm unsure at what point in my code I should start using them. I feel the answer should be "as soon as possible".

Prior to PHP 7 a lot of my code looks like the example class. My Controller would initialize a class and pass the POST variables to it. I would then do variable type checking within the class to make sure all the vars are correct.

```
class User {
     public function createUser($username, $password, $some_float)
     {
          // Check types, validate vars and create user
     }
}
```

With PHP 7, I can do this

```
class User {
     public function createUser(string $username, string $password, float $some_float)
     {
          // Validate vars and create user
     }
}
```

If I was to go with the second example, it would mean moving a lot of the type checking code out of the User class, and into the Controller calling it. I don't really like the idea of bloating out my controllers with type checking.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I don't know if there's really a correct answer.

Comment: I agree with @Don'tPanic, but if you don't want to type check in your controller why not just leave it in your model? You don't have to use type checking in a controller.

Comment: Why would you have to move type checking code to the controller? The specification of a typehint *is* your type checking code.

Comment: What does your current `createUser` method do in the case of invalid types? If you're already using an exception model, then you can just adjust your controller to catch `Throwable` instead, since the internal `TypeError` class implements it. If you're relying on the return value, then yes, you would need additional refactoring. Bear in mind that PHP will perform type conversion to your scalar type-hints (unless using *strict_types*), so the variable types don't need to be exact.

Comment: Depends on where the data is coming from, if it's from user input, it should be checked ASAP.  If it's from the database, then the type should be fairly predictable.

Comment: I'd argue that the controller is the exact place you want to do type checking since this is where you are ingesting user input. One would argue that you use coercive type hints in your controller and then strict in your model.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Because it leads to self documenting code and makes it clear to other developers, strict typing has a lot of benefits.

Comment: @iainn It throws different exceptions like you mentioned.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes I'm talking from user input, my models already match the types in the database.

Comment: Adding code to explicitly check types is certainly not what I'd call self-documenting or strict typing. It adds unnecessary complexity and increases the chances of bugs. Native typehints *are* self-documenting, strict, simple, and clear. They'll be picked up by API doc generators and IDEs for autocompletion -- neither of which you'll get with a manual type check.

Comment: @Aknosis This is my thinking, the entire model should be typed, it seems sensible. But then I don't want my controllers bloated with all the type checking you have to do from POSTs.

Comment: If you're already catching exceptions in your controllers then I'd suggest adding the type-hints, changing the catch block to `catch (Throwable...` and seeing what happens. It sounds like that'll give you the best of both worlds, without re-architecting too much all at once. That said, we're certainly drifting into opinion-based at this point.

Comment: @AlexHowansky User input usually originates from POST. Providing a POST key is set, it will be a string or an array. If you try to pass an array in to example 2, you will get a fatal error. The point of my question is, should I leave my type checking within my models (no scalar declarations) or should I move my type checking out of the models so that they can implement scalar declarations.

Comment: _"you will get a fatal error"_ No, you will get an exception of TypeError. I'm confused as to why you think you can't use typehints on the models or why you'd need to move the typehints to the controller. The controller will do something like: `User::createUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);` and the typehints on the model will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe any answer to this question will be opiniated to a certain extend and we are in a grey area, if it actually fits to stackoverlow. Nevertheless, I will try to answer as objective as possible.

According to my experiance, *robustness* is higher priority in compare to any other consideration such as run-time performance or maintainability, which would benefit from better developer documentation.

Based on that, keep the input validation (type checking is only one kind of input validation. There are also range checks etc.) as close as possibe to the place where the inputs are actually used. In your case, that seems to be the models for a Model-Controller-View Application. To my understanding of your example code, the user class, would be a model.

**Rationale:** The code will evolve in time and the risk that you or worse, your co-workers make a change in one place and forget about the second place increases. In other words, if changes are necessary, that risk is smaller, if the related parts of the code are close to each other.

*Additional* earlier checks, e.g. at HTML5 Level, using javascript or at the controller level have their advantages, they might be even necessary, but they are "far" from the code where the inputs are really used, so I would not give up the checks at the lower level. Ideally, implement all of these checks. If your time is tight, sacrifice the HTML5 Level checks first, then any javascript checks and then controller level checks. But dropping the model level checks is a no-go. In other words, start implementing checks at the model level and then implement the higher level ones.

That fits to your last sentence:

> I don't really like the idea of bloating out my controllers with type
>   checking.

This also implies that the controlers are a good place for much of the error handling.

Side note: The same goes to input validation within the database. This is your "last line of defence". If bad data leaks in there, corrective actions will be very expensive. So add as much input validation into the database structure as possible. In worst case these restrictions can be relaxed later and your database would remain clean.